# Correct linejoins at tikz to path

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, tikz-path

I would like to use a to-path, where a node is placed in the middle. This breaks the linejoins between the single segments. Therefore, i added short segments at the end and begin of each path. This works with the following code. Nevertheless,
if the target coordinate is a node, there seems to be a problem. Is it possible to fix this within the path-code?
Or does anyone has another idea to get proper linejoins in another way?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{mypath/.style = {to path={
%Save current path, because (\tikztostart) at the coordinate-command will start a new one
\pgfextra{\pgfsyssoftpath@getcurrentpath{\my@saved@path}
}

(\tikztostart) coordinate (start)%necessary to get correct coordinates in the case of relativ start/end or constructions like ((node1)-|(node2))
(\tikztotarget) coordinate (end)

\pgfextra{
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{start}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{end}{center}}
    \edef\path@direction{\pgfmathresult}%Calculate direction(angle) of path
    \pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath{\my@saved@path}%%switch back to old path
}
%Connect to old path for proper linejoin
--($(start)!.5\pgflinewidth!(end)$)

%set middle node
($(start) ! .5 ! (end)$)node[draw,circle,rotate=\path@direction] (node) {}
%connect
(\tikztostart)--(node.west)
(node.east)--(\tikztotarget)

%Draw a short connection at the end for proper linejoin
($(end)!.5\pgflinewidth!(start)$)--(end)
}}}\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style=thick}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,1.5)node[right]{Ok}; 
    \draw (0,0) to[mypath](0,1) to[mypath](1,1)to[mypath]++(1,-1);
  \begin{scope}[xshift=2.5cm]
    \draw (0,1.5)node[right]{Ok}; 
    \draw (1,1) coordinate(A);
    \draw (0,0) to[mypath](0,1) to[mypath](A)to[mypath]++(1,-1);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
    \draw (0,1.5)node[right]{Not Ok};
    \draw (1,1) node(A){};
    \draw (0,0) to[mypath](0,1) to[mypath](A)to[mypath]++(1,-1);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=7.5cm]
    \draw (0,1.5)node[right]{Ok};
    \draw (1,1) node(A){};
    \draw (0,0) to[mypath](0,1) to[mypath](A.center)to[mypath]++(1,-1);
  \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
I have no idea why, but it seems to work, if i change line 11 to:

```
(\tikztotarget)++(0,0) coordinate (end)
```

**EDIT2/Solution:**

Insert within the \pgfextra{...} around line 14:

`\let\tikz@moveto@waiting=\relax`

Best regards,

Stefan

PS: The shown code is just a MWE to illustrate the problem, the original problem is described [here](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/64) and occurs within the circuitikz package

Comment: Your code is unsymmetric. What stops you from writing `(start)--($(start)!.5\pgflinewidth!(end)$)` instead of `--($(start)!.5\pgflinewidth!(end)$)`?

Comment: This will break the linejoins, because (start) introduces a moveto command which starts a new path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem begins at the following line:

> ```
> (\tikztostart) coordinate (start)%necessary to get correct coordinates in the case of relativ start/end or constructions like ((node1)-|(node2))
> (\tikztotarget) coordinate (end)
> ```

Here `(\tikztostart)` is `(0,1)` and `(\tikztotarget)` is the node `(A)`.

When Ti*k*Z sees `(\tikztotarget)`, it will try to move to `(A)` because it expects the user to draw something. But it cannot move to `(A)` immediately  because `(A)` is a node, and it can execute a moveto only if it knows the target and calculates the anchorborder(s).

Therefore, instead of executing a moveto, Ti*k*Z will let `\tikz@moveto@waiting` be `A` and read the next few characters to see what you want to do. It then sees `coordinates`, so Ti*K*Z knows that you want to rename the node. It will moveto `(A.center)` and called it `(end)`, so far so good.

Eight lines later, Ti*k*Z encounters

> ```
> --($(start)!.5\pgflinewidth!(end)$)
> ```

The destination of this lineto is not important. The problem is: where is the origin of this lineto? There are two possibilities

- `(2,71)     --($(start)!.5\pgflinewidth!(end)$)`
- `(some node)--($(start)!.5\pgflinewidth!(end)$)`

For the first possibility, Ti*k*Z knows that it had executed a moveto so it will simply execute a lineto. For the second case, it knows that the (`some node`) is pending and it should calculate the anchorborder.

So where is the origin? will... we start this `to`-path from `(0,1)`, so the origin is `(0,1)`, right?

Unfortunately, Ti*k*Z make the decision by checking if `\tikz@moveto@waiting` is empty. Remember eight lines ago `\tikz@moveto@waiting` is let to be `(A)`. So Ti*k*Z thinks that this lineto starts from `(A)` instead of `(0,1)`. And then everything goes wrong.

---

To overcome this problem, you should let `\tikz@moveto@waiting` be empty again in the `\pgfextra`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot ! \let\tikz@moveto@waiting=\relax within pgfextra solved the issue

Comment: could you also have a look at this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369398/correct-linejoins-at-tikz-to-path-ii It is strongly related to this issue